# assigning aliases in .bashrc via echo '...' >> .bashrc

Tags: alias, bashrc, echo

running cat .bashrc gives me these two lines at the end:

```
alias remove='rm -i'
alias chamber='ls -a -i -l'
```

when I run

```
remove
```

followed by a file name I get a successful removal with confirmation prompt. when I run

```
chamber
```

I get

> ```
> chamber: command not found
> ```

I used the echo convention to enter both

```
echo 'alias chamber='ls -a -i -l'' >> .bashrc
```

When I inspected in nano the inside quotes didn't appear so I entered them manually.

1. How do I get the command to register?
2. How do I ensure the inside quotes write to `.bashrc`?

Comment: 1) logout and log back in

2) use double quotes on the outside

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` statement seem not correct. Can you try with: `echo 'alias chamber="ls -a -i -l"' >> .bashrc` and apply new changes by `source .bashrc`